# Error after running the command "npx react-native start"

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, development-environment

```
Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
        at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
        at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
        at stableHash (C:\Users\Anupam K Krishnan\Desktop\lcorn\myProject\node_modules\metro-cache\src\stableHash.js:19:8)
        at Object.getCacheKey (C:\Users\Anupam K Krishnan\Desktop\lcorn\myProject\node_modules\metro-transform-worker\src\index.js:593:7)
        at getTransformCacheKey (C:\Users\Anupam K Krishnan\Desktop\lcorn\myProject\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\getTransformCacheKey.js:24:19)
        at new Transformer (C:\Users\Anupam K Krishnan\Desktop\lcorn\myProject\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Transformer.js:48:9)
        at C:\Users\Anupam K Krishnan\Desktop\lcorn\myProject\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:22:29
        at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:497:9) {
      opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
      library: 'digital envelope routines',
      reason: 'unsupported',
      code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
    }
```

*I'm a beginner at* ***react-native***
*Kindly tell how can I resolve this*

Comment: Which node version you are using?

Comment: It's **17.1.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to downgrade your `node`. I usually downgrade to `node v15.10.0` and it works.

What you can do:

1. `nvm install 15.10.0`
2. `nvm use v15`

install all your packages again `expo`, `react-native`, etc.

Comment: Thank you @jted95 the issue got resolved by your method

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error, but for some reason switching node versions with nvm did not work. Removing nvm and using the system's node v16.5 solved the problem...